# Gulp critical css not working with Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, gulp, laravel-elixir, critical-css

When I run the **gulp critical** command, elixir is left loading for a while and then gives an error in the console:

```
var elixir      = require('laravel-elixir');
var BrowserSync = require('laravel-elixir-browsersync');
var gulp        = require('gulp');
var critical    = require('critical');

gulp.task('critical', function() {
  critical.generate({
    src: 'http://regalospersonales.local',
    css: 'public/css/style.css',
    width: 1280,
    height: 600,
    dest: 'public/css/critical.css'
  });
});

elixir(function(mix) {

    BrowserSync.init();

    mix.BrowserSync(
    {
        proxy           : "regalospersonales.local",
        logPrefix       : "Laravel Eixir BrowserSync",
        logConnections  : false,
        reloadOnRestart : false,
        notify          : false,
        files           : ["app/**/*", 
                           "public/**/*",
                           "resources/views/**/*",
                          ]
    });

    mix.sass([
        "main.scss",
    ],'public/css/style.css');

    mix.task('critical');

});
```

I have correctly installed the package with node npm.

[image]

What's the problem?

Comment: *<quote>...and then gives an error in the console</quote>*, maybe also show us?

Comment: @ThomasMoors yes, I edit the main post

Comment: https://github.com/cmderdev/cmder/issues/700#issuecomment-155321519 ?

Comment: @ThomasMoors I don't understand

Comment: As per the screenshots the problem is with Penthouse. So the solutions is to increase the timeout value in Penthouse package's `index.js`. It causes due to the extra loading time of external resources.